# Remove p2p-dev-wlp1s0 device, network manager

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

`nmcli` output (among other items):

```
p2p-dev-wlp1s0: disconnected
        "p2p-dev-wlp1s0"
        wifi-p2p, hw
```

How can I remove this `p2p-dev-wlp1s0` device? It's used for wireless peer-to-peer connections but I don't need it. I tried through wpa_supplicant.conf but no difference. I think it's created by network-manager.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a network interface, use:

```
nmcli device delete p2p-dev-wlp1s0
nmcli con reload
```

Add `p2p_disabled=1` to your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file as documented [here](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf).

```
# Disable P2P functionality
# p2p_disabled=1
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work:
`Error: Device 'p2p-dev-wlp1s0' (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6) deletion failed: This device is not a software device or is not realized`.
I tried using sudo also.

Comment: @Krackout See my edit. Please.

Comment: `p2p_disabled=1` in wpa_supplicant.conf doesn't remove the device either. I had already tried this, quote from my question, "I tried through wpa_supplicant.conf but no difference"; sorry for not mentioning the specifics. I tried making `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` (non-existent in my system) and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. `/etc/wpa_supplicant` directory was present before I take any action, some scripts are there.

Comment: @Krackout What is your wpasupplicant version?

Comment: wpa_supplicant v2.10, the standard package supplied by Debian 12.4 bookworm.